# Filtering zsh array by wildcard

Tags: zsh

Given a Zsh array myarray, I can make out of it a subset array

```
set -A subarray
for el in $myarray
do 
  if [[ $el =~ *x*y* ]]
  then
    subarray+=($el)
  fi
done
```

which, in this example, contains all elements from *myarray* which have somewhere an *x* and an *y*, in that order.

Question:

Given the plethora of array operations available in zsh, is there an easier way to achieve this? I checked the man page and the [zsh-lovers page](http://grml.org/zsh/zsh-lovers.html), but couldn't find anything suitable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
subarray=(${(M)myarray:#*x*y*z})
```

You can find the explanation in the [section about Parameter Expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) in the *zsh* manpage. It is a bit hidden as `${name:#pattern}` without the flag `(M)` does the opposite of what you want:

> **`${name:#pattern}`**
>
> If the `pattern` matches the value of `name`, then substitute the empty string; otherwise, just substitute the value of `name`. If `name` is an array the matching array elements are removed (use the `(M)` flag to remove the non-matched elements).