# zsh parameter expansion that filters out array elements that match a pattern

Tags: zsh, parameter-expansion

What zsh parameter expansion can filter out array elements that match a pattern (like what `grep -v` does)?

Comment: For all that I know, you can only search an array for a pattern (and even then, the pattern is a glob and not a regexp), but you can not create a subarry by providing a filtering expression.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks. What is the syntax for the zsh glob array search?

Comment: `${array[(I)$value]}` yields the index where $value matches the array element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering zsh array by wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872135/filtering-zsh-array-by-wildcard)

Comment: @hchbaw Yes. Thanks.